# Visual Studio 2022 Container Tools Extension error

Tags: azure, docker-compose, azure-functions, visual-studio-2022

Got this error `An error occured during the stream operation` on Visual studio Community 2022 v17.9.2.

Below is the message when clicked on.

[image]

The debug of the Azure Function project is failed with the error message:

[image]

Any idea please?

Comment: Please provide your function code.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be due to the issue with the code parsing a value, related to setting or parameter.

- Debug the code without running the container.
- Stop running the Docker Image and Reboot the Docker Desktop.

I have created a .NET 6 function and able to debug the Containerized function.

```
Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5571 Commit hash: N/A +9a5b604f0b846df7de3eb37b423a9eba8baa1152 (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.30.0.22097

[2024-03-14T16:26:09.624Z] Found /home/site/wwwroot/FunctionApp16.csproj. Using for user secrets file configuration.
Skipping 'AzureWebJobsStorage' from local settings as it's already defined in current environment variables.
Skipping 'FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME' from local settings as it's already defined in current environment variables.
Skipping 'AzureWebJobsScriptRoot' from local settings as it's already defined in current environment variables.
[2024-03-14T16:26:13.879Z] Extension Bundle not loaded. Loading extensions from /home/site/wwwroot/bin/Debug/net6.0/bin. BundleConfigured: False, PrecompiledFunctionApp: False, LegacyBundle: False, DotnetIsolatedApp: False, isLogicApp: False
[2024-03-14T16:26:13.882Z] Script Startup resetting load context with base path: '/home/site/wwwroot/bin/Debug/net6.0/bin'.
[2024-03-14T16:26:15.939Z] Reading functions metadata (Host)
[2024-03-14T16:26:16.000Z] 1 functions found (Host)

Functions:

    Function1: [GET,POST] http://localhost:30892/api/Function1

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-03-14T16:26:21.593Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '00000000000000000000000025B47841'.
[2024-03-14T16:26:30.055Z] Executing HTTP request: {

[2024-03-14T16:26:30.055Z]   "requestId": "cbf3d48d-6863-4a14-ba18-bd4544eb3803",
[2024-03-14T16:26:30.055Z]   "method": "GET",
[2024-03-14T16:26:30.055Z]   "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/122.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/122.0.0.0",
[2024-03-14T16:26:30.055Z]   "uri": "/api/Function1"
[2024-03-14T16:26:30.055Z] }
[2024-03-14T16:26:30.549Z] Executing 'Function1' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=5cd41d23-88fd-4064-9ce5-d6049f2d4995)
[2024-03-14T16:26:30.653Z] C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.
[2024-03-14T16:26:30.805Z] Executed 'Function1' (Succeeded, Id=5cd41d23-88fd-4064-9ce5-d6049f2d4995, Duration=301ms)
[2024-03-14T16:26:30.878Z] Executed HTTP request: {

[2024-03-14T16:26:30.878Z]   "requestId": "cbf3d48d-6863-4a14-ba18-bd4544eb3803",
[2024-03-14T16:26:30.878Z]   "identities": "",
[2024-03-14T16:26:30.878Z]   "status": "200",
[2024-03-14T16:26:30.878Z]   "duration": "821"
[2024-03-14T16:26:30.878Z] }
```

[image]